# Is there any country that stopped releasing data on youth joblessness in the past aside from China?

Tags: economy, international, employment

> China has suspended the release of data on youth joblessness, which
> hit a record high in June, citing a need to examine its method for
> calculating the key economic indicator. The country’s National Bureau
> of Statistics (NBS) released monthly economic data today (Aug. 15),
> reporting that the unemployment rate remained steady at 5.3%, up 0.1%
> from July. Specific figures on youth unemployment ages 16 to 24,
> usually in the report, were not included.

https://qz.com/china-suspends-youth-unemployment-data-amid-record-high-1850739032

Is there any country that stopped releasing data on youth joblessness in the past aside from China? China just started publishing this data again, but it did stop not long ago, so I was wondering if other countries did the same in the past.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the past 5+ years, the indian government headed by Prime Minister Narendra Modi has been been accused by the opposition of [deliberately withholding data](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/nda-is-no-data-available-govt-with-no-accountability-rahul-gandhi/articleshow/93071721.cms) on various economic factors (not just unemployment). But since you ask only about unemployment:

> The Modi government’s relationship with economic data started on a low in 2019.
>
> The National Sample Survey Office conducted its latest periodic labour force survey between July 2017 and June 2018 – a period considered crucial because it would reveal just what impact demonetisation had on India’s working population. Two members of the National Statistical Commission resigned when the Centre refused to make this data public, and yet the government didn’t blink.
>
> In January 2019, Business Standard published a series of articles leaking the survey’s results. Unemployment was at a 45-year high, the NSSO had found, and youth unemployment was substantially higher than in previous years. (Source: [Six Numbers the Modi Government Did Not Want You to Know in 2019](https://thewire.in/politics/narendra-modi-data-npr-nrc-economy))

---

> We all know that millions of people are unemployed due to coronavirus and lockdown. Since the outbreak of the coronavirus in India, the government has not collected data on unemployment, migrants who lost their lives in lockdowns across the country, student deaths who died from the deadly virus.
>
> On September 14, three members of parliament asked the Ministry of Labour and Employment of India, has the government conducted any assessment of the job losses of workers caused by the Covid-19 crisis? and if so, the details of the assessment. To this, Santosh Gangwar, the Minister of State for Labor and Employment, answered that the government has no data.
>
> Why is the government lying? In April 2020, CMIE data revealed, that the ballooning number of job losses among wage earners is a serious cause for concern. Still, the Modi Government didn’t take any action. And now when it asked about data, it said it doesn’t have any data on the impact of COVID-19 on the job. (Source: [Why Modi Lead BJP Government has No data about anything, but still India mein ‘Sab theek hai’ ka ‘Sab Changa Si’?](https://www.inventiva.co.in/trends/modi-no-data/))

---

> It is not just that the economy was not able to recover from these two shocks that is important. The government, to cover its tracks, started saying there was no data available on employment. There is a fundamental fallacy there. If you do not have data on the unorganised sector, how do you have data on the GDP? How do you say the economy is growing at 7%? If you don’t have data on 45% of your output, your GDP data can’t be accurate ... For the lack of official data on unemployment, we have to rely on alternate data on the unorganised sector. The CMIE data shows huge number of jobs lost in the unorganised sector. If one takes that data into account, the unorganised sector’s contribution to the GDP post-Demonetisation was minus 4.5%. If you balance it out with the organised sector, the GDP growth comes down to 0%. (Source: [How do I vote for a Government which admits it has no data?](https://www.nationalheraldindia.com/opinion/how-do-i-vote-for-a-government-which-admits-it-has-no-data))

---

> A World Bank report concluded that 40 million migrant jobs were impacted/lost in India in April 2020 . But when the Government was first asked how many migrants had lost their jobs, the answer was that it had no data. (Source: [The significance of the ‘there is no data’ answer](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/the-significance-of-the-there-is-no-data-answer/article62105613.ece))

More here - ['We Have No Data': Govt's Answers To Questions On Job Losses, Migrant Exodus, Death Of COVID Warriors](https://thelogicalindian.com/trending/india-no-data-govt-23882) and [Without data, the government’s policy prescriptions are just guesswork](https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/columns/harish-damodaran-data-government-policy-prescriptions-guesswork-8589621/).